# Youtube is sending wrong thumbnail when when retrieving data using oembed

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am extracting youtube playlist data from youtube using oembed jason format like below

```
  http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url={playlisturl}&format=json
```

e.g

https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0eyrZgxdwhyeIDc3EA4XGsI9HoWLc6nF&format=json

If you open obove link it sends the playlist details in JSON format which I'm using in my code, but in many playlist, thumbnail url is the url of the second video instead of the thumbnail of playlist?

Does any one know about this problem and can guide what what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue as reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134417363#comment2)

So if you need the first thumbnail, I would recommend the same solution mentioned in the link. That is, to call PlaylistItems.list and get the thumbnail of the first item.